# Website isn't accessible from our company network, but accessible from outside

Tags: html, apache, tomcat, web

We have a problem with our website, When we try to access the website from within the company (using the company network) it show a message of permission access:

---

[image: screenshot of the error appearing]

*screenshot of the error appearing*

---

However the site works perfectly fine from any other location on the planet.
Does it have to do with our ISP, or it's a bad config within the website ? 
PS: the site was accessible till today, and we did not change anything from our end.

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Internal WAF, firewall, dns resolution difference, VirtualHost only configured for the  external IP not the internal one, ...

Answer (score 0):

Try white-listing your IP/network in webserver. That should do job for you.

Comment: I think it's our router problem, another thing I need to add is we couldn't access our local servers using the web URL, I tried to telned the public ip with the https 443 port from inside the company (using our local network) and it tells me that the host is unreachable, however when I tried connecting from other networks I was be able to telnet the IP.
What do you think I should do ? is it a ISP regulation ? 
Thanks in advance,